# Off topic arguments in comments

Tags: discussion, comments

A little while ago I came across an (off topic) argument in the question comments.  This is not the first time I've seen this.  Is it ok for people to debate about something which is arguably unrelated to the question at hand in a comments thread?  If not, what is the appropriate way to flag an entire comments thread without flagging each individual comment?

The particular comments thread that prompted this question can be found below [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517675/php-sql-how-can-i-get-the-name-of-tables-in-my-database) question.

Comment: The last thing I saw from a moderator on this subject indicated that they prefer each comment flagged individually. Other than that, just flag appropriately. "Not constructive" seems appropriate there.

Comment: I actually enjoyed reading it but heh, it's an actual spam. They should be flagged.

Comment: Well I showed up perhaps after the first wave of the party. And invited the gent to a chat room. There we could clean up our new little mess. But in the meantime he might learn a bit about db's. Sorry for the off-topic chatty msgs to him in what is after the fact